# Trying to remove duplicate jquery scripts

Tags: jquery

I've added this

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
```

before

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

so that I can just use the wordpress included jquery script, and deleted the extra jquery script I've been loading, but when I go to Inspect Element in Chrome I get

submitForm.js:1Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

jquery.colorbox-min.js:4Uncaught ReferenceError: jquery is not defined

I'm guessing that I need to modify submitform.js and jquery.colorbox-min.js, I'm just not sure which way to go, if it helps here is the site, transaction-realty.com

Thanks

Comment: How do you enqueue `sumbitform.js` and `jquery.colorbox-min.js`?

Comment: @Mamaduka I am adding them like this,
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>

Comment: @Mamaduka it turned out they were loading before jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load jquery from WordPress includes, you will need to use `jQuery` instead of the dollar sign `$`, as the latter is reserved for other libraries.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    // Submitform and colorbox init, both will work here.
});
```

But also make sure to avoid the script tags as much as possible, but with wp_enqueue_script in the functions.php (all within `<?php ?>` )

```
function add_our_theme_scripts() {
   $theme_url = get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/';
   // Add the wordpress version of jQuery. 
   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-submit-form', $theme_url . 'submit-form.js';
   // similarly for colorbox if it is added through the theme.
} // END function add_our_theme_scripts()

// It should be hooked to init or wp_print_scripts and not wp_head.
add_action( 'init', 'add_our_theme_scripts' );
```

Now if you wish to make it more simple and manageable put the previous code in a separate file and add that to the above function too.

### jQuery conflict

You can also try [jQuery no conflict mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) like below.

```
  // example var myJQ. 
  myJQ = jQuery.noConflict();

  myJQ( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
      // scripts here.
  });
```

But be careful though, $ sign will not be available after you enter noConflict mode, so make sure you use myJQ ( example here ) consistently.